# How to return conditional element and first element of an array?

Tags: reactjs

I have following code:

```
    const items = itemsInfo.map(product => {
        if (product.type === "fruit") {
            return (
                <div>
                    {product.name} {product.weight}
                </div>
            )
        }

        //need to return just one element if it is not a fruit
        return <div> {product.name} </div>
    });
```

If itemsInfo array has a fruit, it should return the element with extra data, there will always be just one fruit in the array.

If it's something else other than fruit, it should return just first non-fruit element of the array. There should be maximum of two items returned ([fruit + non-fruit] or [fruit] or [non-fruit]).

I don't know how to return first product of the array when it also has to check if there is conditional if statement in play.

It has to be in react

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  What should `items` contain after this statement?  What does it currently contain and how is that incorrect?  `.map()` will always produce an array the same length as the input array, so if the goal is to sometimes produce an array and sometimes produce a single element then `.map()` alone is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Why do you need to iterate on the array at all if only the first two items have any affect on the result?

Answer (score 0):

For the component to be rendered it needs to return JSX not an array as **map** does. It needs to be wrapped on a function as shown below:

```
import React from 'react'

const itemsInfo = [
  {type: "fruit", name: "Apple", weight:  1},
  {type: "other", name: "Other", weight:  3},
  {type: "fruit", name: "Mango", weight:  2},
  
]

const Items = ()=> {
  return (
    <>
      {
        itemsInfo.map(product => {
          if (product.type === "fruit") {
              return (
                  <div>
                      {product.name} {product.weight}
                  </div>
              )
          }else{
            //need to return just one element if it is not a fruit  
            return <div> {product.name} </div>
          }
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}


function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Items />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Not sure if I understood this part correctly, but on the example if is not a fruit it will not render the **weight** property and will only display the name.
If no need to render at all just remove the else part.
If different please share an example of the array to get the idea.